# How to compare Firebird Database TIMESTAMP with PHP time() value?

Tags: php, timestamp, firebird

My database has a data field of type TIMESTAMP. It's called "mytime". I get a number from php's time() function. e.g:

```
print time();
```

Then I query the db:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where mytime > 1369157557
```

It complains:

```
conversion error from string "1369157557"
```

I'm guessing you can't compare a PHP timestamp with a Firebird timestamp. Why not? And how do I get around it?

Comment: Maybe use quotes - SELECT * FROM mytable where mytime > '1369157557'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options: convert that unix timestamp to a Firebird timestamp before comparison. Or do something like described in [this message on the Firebird-Support list](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2009/6/102699.html):

```
select DATEDIFF(second, timestamp '1/1/1970 00:00:00', current_timestamp)
from rdb$database
```

Or specifically in your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
where DATEDIFF(second, timestamp '1/1/1970 00:00:00', mytime) > 1369157557
```

Just keep in mind that the times stored in your database may not be stored in UTC, and in that case you need to take the offset against UTC into consideration as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function. Be aware though that php and mysql may disagree, both a few seconds-wise as timezone-wise.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mytime) > 1369157557
```

Comment: The question is about Firebird, not MySQL.